# How to write user data to firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I don't know how to write user entered data into his specific folder in the database.

I presume I should start from describing an action creator like so:

```
export const updateUser = values => {
  const userId = AsyncStorage.getItem("userId");
  fetch(`https://sample-app.firebaseio.com/users/${userId}.json`,
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {
     ...values
    }
  })
}
```

But my database rules are set to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I can't store anything into the database

[image: database]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing .json at the end of request .check https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database

Comment: It seems like you have to change your rules.
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }

Comment: @JP_ But these rules are meant to stay this way and only authorized user should read and write data from his folder of the database.

Comment: @MihaiCiobanu But in the case you are not authorized user you have to put rules like this:
"rules": { ".read": true, ".write": true }
otherwise It's not allow to write any data

Comment: @JP_ The rules are set ok, meaning I don't want unauthorized users to read any of the data, and the ones that are authorized - to read only their personal userId folder from the users.

Comment: Can I know why are you using fetch with firebase? https://rnfirebase.io/ is a amazing library to work with react native firebase